A movie about a female serial killer
I'm looking for a movie from around the 1990's-2000's. I can remember several scenes from this movie, but not the title, or any actors. I thought it had Edward Norton in it as the main man, or Helena Bonham Carter in it as the main woman. But I looked at both of their IMDb history and couldn't find anything, so maybe these actors just looked like them from that time period?
A young woman is killing men at night on dates, not sure how many, but serial killer or revenge on men style (unsure if she was ever wronged or raped). She is at the end of her leash and is planning on ending it all soon, on her next date maybe. I think she had a pill to take to kill herself. 
The main man is 'getting back out there' dating, and unknowingly sets up a date with this woman who is a killer. His friend talks with him about the upcoming date and warns to be careful as there is a killer on the streets they haven't caught. Not sure if they are investigating her, or unrelated to the situation.
The two go on their date, go back to a room alone, and talk all night till the sun comes up, with no murders or death of any kind. The scene cuts out as they are falling asleep next to each other in bed, and cuts back in to a flash-forward scene of them being woken up by two or so kids jumping in their bed 5 years after that night?

This sounds like 2007's Sex and Death 101.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_and_Death_101
Winona Ryder plays the woman serial killer, and Simon Baker is the male lead. She was previously in an abusive relationship. She poisons the men, sending them into comas, but some survive.
The male lead and"Death Nell," as the woman is called in the news, go on a date and debate taking the same poison she had been using on her victims. They decide to be there for each other instead.
The reason the movie is called Sex and Death 101 is that earlier in the movie, everyone is mailed a list of all the people they will have sex with in their lives. The man's list has 101 people, and it ends with Winona Ryder's character, implying they'll be together the rest of his life. This is why he was scared to meet her, because he thought it meant she would kill him. 
